# I only want part of the sentence. Is it posible to cut from the start to the end and only get the output i want?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

My file:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="applicationNameSpectrumAnalyzer" Text="Booting Spectrum Analyzer"></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock x:Key="applicationNamePowerMeter" Text="Booting Power Meter"></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock x:Key="applicationNameAnalogDemod" Text="Booting Analog Demod"></TextBlock>

      <!-- ApplicationHeaderBarView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="applicationHeader">Spectrum</sys:String>

      <!-- BuildDetailsTrayView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="buildVersion">V</sys:String>

      <!-- VitalSignsView -->
      <sys:String x:Key="vitalSignCPU">CPU</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="vitalSignRAM">RAM</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="vitalSignMB">MB</sys:String>
```

Desired Output:

```
applicationNameSpectrumAnalyzer Booting Spectrum Analyzer
applicationNamePowerMeter Booting Power Meter
applicationNameAnalogDemod Booting Analog Demod
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you want to implement this? `bash`, `zsh`, `perl`, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

To give you the best answer, we would need more information from you. I suspect that you are only interested in the lines with "TestBlock" tags. You can match those lines first like this.

```
awk -F'"' '/TextBlock/{print $2, $4}' inputfile.txt
```

This will ensure that no other lines are processed.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl way:

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/applicationName/){@A=(/"([^"<]+)"/g); print "@A"}' file 
applicationNameSpectrumAnalyzer Booting Spectrum Analyzer
applicationNamePowerMeter Booting Power Meter
applicationNameAnalogDemod Booting Analog Demod
```

Answer (score -1):

I think i figured it out, i just need the command. I used:

```
awk -F '"' '{print $2 " " $4}' test2.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information. This command does not produce the output you asked for.